# How to add d3 GWT wrapper to vaadin?

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, d3.js, vaadin

I tried adding the d3 gtw wrapper found [here](https://github.com/gwtd3/gwt-d3) to Vaadin. But since I am newby to Vaadin/GWT I am a bit confused as to how exactly I can add and use the wrapper.
I tried adding the wrapper to the project as per manual using maven but I kept getting  javax.servlet.ServletException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/gwtd3/api/D3. I get no warning in eclipse and I can see the documentaton for the classes when coding.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use d3.js library you have 3 options.

1. Add d3.js using [@JavaScript](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/annotations/JavaScript.html) annotation. This option is explained in details [on Vaadin website](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integrating+a+JavaScript+component).
2. Better approach (more clean, and easier to maintain in longterm) would be to write custom Vaadin component based on GWT. You can add and use your d3.js file while producing new GWT component. After that export it to the jar, recompile widgetsets and you can use it your Vaadin app. This approach is explained in details [here](https://dzone.com/articles/using-gwt-widgets-vaadin-7).
3. Check out already developed addon for [Vaadin Freecode Charts and D3 Wrapper](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/freecode-charts-and-d3-wrapper) . Maybe functionality provided in this one will be just enough for you.

Comment: Very Resourceful, thank you! I've tried 1 and 3 already, but I want to use the above mentioned wrapper as is provides exactly what I need so I'll  try option 2 now.

Comment: Glad to help and welcome on StackOverflow. If an answer helped you, you may want to upvote it or even accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: As useful as your answer is, and I tried the examples provided, but still can't quite figure it out. I am very new to this so please bear with me. I basically have 2 jars, one with the d3 lib and one with the API both wrapped as GWT modules or widgets. How do I use that in Vaadin to draw a graph?

Comment: I will look into it later and provide the example after work